# JavaScript - function is not defined when loaded from external file

Tags: javascript, function

I've just started to play around with JavaScript in order to learn some new stuff but I have a problem with functions. It works fine when the functions are right in the html file but when I try to load it from external file it says that the functions are not defined. Can you help me please?

```js
function showEurope(){
    document.getElementById('europeImage').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('worldImage').style.display='none';
    }
    
function showWorld(){
    document.getElementById('worldImage').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('europeImage').style.display='none';
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="showEurope()">Europe</button>
    <button onclick="showWorld()">World</button>
   <p>
    <img src="world.jpg" alt= "The World" id= "worldImage" style="display:none">
    <img src="europe.gif" alt= "Europe" id = "europeImage" style="display:none">
   </p> 
   <script src = "/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your file structure is important for this can you share this? I assume you have to do src = "./index.js

Comment: `src = "/index.js"` will work only on server, if everything is in your local drive replace `"/index.js"` with just `"index.js"` (remove `/`)

Comment: @alex That was it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the path of the js file relative to the HTML file is specified correctly inside the `src` attribute.
For instance, if the two files are in the same directory, then the path should be `src = "index.js"`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the js file in the same directory as the HTML file:

Remove the opening "/" from the script tag.
script src = "/index.js" type="text/javascript"

It should be:
script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"

Works on my box ;)